# Reputation for a Revival badge question : display or calculation bug?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

[In my Reputation tab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/14625/tomdemuyt?tab=reputation), I can see that I got 3 upvotes for an older question for which I got a bronze revival badge, but I don't see the 30 reputation for it under 'today', nor for the week or month. ( Bad me, my previous upped question was on 22 November ;)

Display bug or real bug?  This is 9 hours after the last upvote.

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/36590/22222), which was originally made CW?

Comment: I remember upvoting that post yesterday (actually given UTC offset it should count as *today*) - was unvoted then, and a nice **target** to shoot at :) ...but it being CW would explain the no-rep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community wiki posts don't award reputation, which explains why you see the upvote records but not a corresponding increase in reputation.

If you clicked the "make community wiki" checkbox by accident when posting the answer, a moderator can undo that for you.

Comment: I must have clicked that by accident, how do I ask a moderator?

Comment: @tomdemuyt You can flag your post (there's a "flag" link at the bottom) and leave a moderator a note asking them to remove community wiki from the post. I took care of this one already, and you should see your 30 rep back. Enjoy!